# PHP API Youtube Uploads, exception: Failed to start the resumable upload, upload must be sent to the upload URL

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to build a server application for uploading videos to YouTube. In my server application, the user can upload a video directly to my YouTube channel to make it public.

[image]

1. The client part of my application acquires the video and uploads it to my server.
2. My server then uses YouTube API to upload the video to my YouTube channel.

To make this work, I created a dummy Web Application that can capture the refresh token generated and I have stored it in a `key.txt` file

```
{"access_token":"MYTOKEN","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"created":1435654774}
```

The `upload_video.php` script will automatically update `"key.txt"` file if `access_token` is out of date. This is the code from `upload_video.php`:

```
$key = file_get_contents('key.txt');

$application_name = 'YouTube_Upload'; 
$client_secret    = 'MY_CLIENT_SECRET';
$client_id        = 'MY_CLIENT_ID';
$scope            = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner');

$videoPath        = "Test.f4v";
$videoTitle       = "A tutorial video";
$videoDescription = "A video tutorial on how to upload to YouTube";
$videoCategory    = "22";
$videoTags        = array("youtube", "tutorial");

try{
    // Client init
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName($application_name);
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setAccessToken($key);
    $client->setScopes($scope);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);

    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

        /**
         * Check to see if access token has expired. If so, get a new one and save it to file for future use.
         */
        if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $newToken = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
            $client->refreshToken($newToken->refresh_token);
            file_put_contents('key.txt', $client->getAccessToken());
        }

        $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

        // Create a snipet with title, description, tags and category id
        $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
        $snippet->setTitle($videoTitle);
        $snippet->setDescription($videoDescription);
        $snippet->setCategoryId($videoCategory);
        $snippet->setTags($videoTags);

        // Create a video status with privacy status. Options are "public", "private" and "unlisted".
        $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
        $status->setPrivacyStatus('unlisted');

        // Create a YouTube video with snippet and status
        $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
        $video->setSnippet($snippet);
        $video->setStatus($status);

        // Size of each chunk of data in bytes. Setting it higher leads faster upload (less chunks,
        // for reliable connections). Setting it lower leads better recovery (fine-grained chunks)
        $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
        // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
        $client->setDefer(true);

        // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
        $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

        // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
        $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
            $client,
            $insertRequest,
            'video/*',
            null,
            true,
            $chunkSizeBytes
        );
        $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));

        // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
        $status = false;
        $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
        while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
            $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
            $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
        }

        fclose($handle);

        /**
         * Video has successfully been upload
         */
        if ($status->status['uploadStatus'] == 'uploaded') {
            // Actions to perform for a successful upload
            // ......
        }

        // If want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
        $client->setDefer(true);

    } else{
        // @TODO Log error
        echo 'Problems creating the client';
    }

} catch(Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    print "Google_Service_Exception ".$e->getCode(). " message is ".$e->getMessage();
    print "Stack trace is ".$e->getTraceAsString();
}catch (Exception $e) {
    print "Exception ".$e->getCode(). " message is ".$e->getMessage();
    print "Stack trace is ".$e->getTraceAsString();
}
```

When the script runs, it raise this exception:

```
Exception 0 message is Failed to start the resume-able upload (HTTP 400: global, Uploads must be sent to the upload URL. Re-send this request to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=status,snippet&uploadType=resumable)Stack trace is 
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\src\Google\Http\MediaFileUpload.php(136): Google_Http_MediaFileUpload->getResumeUri()
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\resumable_upload.php(100): Google_Http_MediaFileUpload->nextChunk('\x00\x00\x00\x1Cftypf4v \x00\x00\x00...')
#2 {main}
```

exception raise on `getResumeUri()` (line 281) in `Google_Http_MediaFileUpload`, i have var dump the response from google

```
Google_Http_Request Object
(
    [batchHeaders:Google_Http_Request:private] => Array
        (
            [Content-Type] => application/http
            [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => binary
            [MIME-Version] => 1.0
        )

    [queryParams:protected] => Array
        (
            [part] => status,snippet
            [uploadType] => resumable
        )

    [requestMethod:protected] => POST
    [requestHeaders:protected] => Array
        (
            [content-type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
            [authorization] => Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            [content-length] => 187
            [x-upload-content-type] => video/*
            [x-upload-content-length] => 10201286
            [expect] => 
        )

    [baseComponent:protected] => https://www.googleapis.com//upload
    [path:protected] => /youtube/v3/videos
    [postBody:protected] => {"snippet":{"categoryId":"22","description":"A video tutorial on how to upload to YouTube","tags":["youtube","tutorial"],"title":"A tutorial video"},"status":{"privacyStatus":"unlisted"}}
    [userAgent:protected] => 
    [canGzip:protected] => 
    [responseHttpCode:protected] => 400
    [responseHeaders:protected] => Array
        (
            [x-guploader-uploadid] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            [location] => https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=status,snippet&uploadType=resumable
            [vary] => Origin
X-Origin
            [content-type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
            [content-length] => 468
            [date] => Fri, 10 Jul 2015 09:54:30 GMT
            [server] => UploadServer
            [alternate-protocol] => 443:quic,p=1
        )

    [responseBody:protected] => {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "wrongUrlForUpload",
    "message": "Uploads must be sent to the upload URL. Re-send this request to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=status,snippet&uploadType=resumable"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Uploads must be sent to the upload URL. Re-send this request to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=status,snippet&uploadType=resumable"
 }
}

    [expectedClass:protected] => Google_Service_YouTube_Video
    [expectedRaw:protected] => 
    [accessKey] => 
)
```

What is wrong?
Thanks for any help and sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with PHP Client Library of Google API. Go to GOOGLE_LIB_PATH/Http/MediaFileUpload.php and replace this line:

```
$this->request->setBaseComponent($base . '/upload');
```

With this one:

```
$this->request->setBaseComponent($base . 'upload');
```

Try again and share the results. I faced a similar problem with Google Pubsub API where API path set by library was incorrect.

Comment: fixed in the latest commits on github

Answer (score 1):

I hope you need Resumable Uploads(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol)

Then use [this](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/resumable_upload.php) without any modification.

Also check if the video format is supported from https://support.google.com/youtube/troubleshooter/2888402?hl=en

Comment: My code is already inspired by resumable_upload.php example of google.

Comment: @ar099968 Your code is unable to get the resumable Uri which means that it can not be uploaded as resumable, as pointed out by Mithun

Comment: @FurhanShabir I do not understand. I have used a resumable example from google...

Comment: @ar099968 Yes, but then you are violating the rule of type of allowed files to be uploaded to YouTube. ".f4v" is not supported. To double check this proposition, try uploading an ".mp4" file with same code and see if that succeeds. Let me know the outcome please.

Comment: @FurhanShabir I tried with a * .mp4 but raises the same exception

Comment: @ar099968 Go to MediaFileUpload.php in GoogleLib/Http folder and find this line:
$response = $this->client->getIo()->makeRequest($this->request);
Then immediately after this, print_r($response);exit;
Please share the result.
Also print_r($this->request) too and share the results.

Comment: @FurhanShabir the exception is raised before reaching that point (MediaFileUpload.php line 136 Google_Http_MediaFileUpload->getResumeUri()).

Comment: @ar099968 Exception occurs when getResumeUri() is called as per your exception stack. so getResumeUri() seems to be called and throws exception.

Comment: @FurhanShabir you know how to fix it?

Comment: @ar099968 First we need to determine the root cause. Can you please share the output of print_r() statements suggested above?

Comment: @FurhanShabir i have update the answer with a output

Comment: @ar099968 Go to MediaFileUpload.php and replace this line:
$this->request->setBaseComponent($base . '/upload');
With
$this->request->setBaseComponent($base . 'upload');
Try again and share the results.

Comment: @FurhanShabir work!! thank you... please write a response for the bounty

Comment: @FurhanS. sir where can I find that line to replace as I am seeing the MediaFileUpload.php but couldn't track the line to be replaced can you help me finding that line.

Answer (score 1):

There is a google method to get the refresh token, so instead of using json_decode :

```
$newToken = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
$client->refreshToken($newToken->refresh_token);
```

You can do :

```
$client->refreshToken( $client->getRefreshToken() );
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what i have tested so far and working fine.

```
$key = trim(file_get_contents('key.txt'));
$scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube';
```