# Set Cache-Control php client on Google Cloud Storage Object

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, cache-control

I have run into this problem and cant find a simple working php example online that can set the object cache-control while uploading to google cloud storage. I know its a setMetadata on object, but I am lost how to do it. using gsutil doesnt cut it because it is not dynamic for a web app.

So far, this is what I have but the setMetadata line throws errors. Can anyone please help correct that line? Note that authorisation token already obtained before the below

```
$file = "xxx.html";
$infotowrite = "999";
$service = new Google_Service_Storage($client);
$obj = new Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject();
$obj->setName($file);
$obj->setMetadata(['cacheControl' => 'public', 'max-age' => '6000']);
$results = $service->objects->insert(
     $bucket_name,
     $obj,
     ['name' => $file, 'mimeType' => 'text/html', 'data' =>   $infotowrite, 'uploadType' => 'media']
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to call the [setCacheControl function](https://api.kdyby.org/source-class-Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject.html#3104-3107).

Here is a working example:

```
$bucket_name = 'my-bucket';
$file = "xxx.html";
$infotowrite = "999";
$service = new Google_Service_Storage($client);
$obj = new Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject();
$obj->setName($file);
$obj->setCacheControl('public, max-age=6000');
$results = $service->objects->insert(
        $bucket_name,
        $obj,
        ['name' => $file, 'mimeType' => 'text/html', 'data' =>   $infotowrite, 'uploadType' => 'media']
);
```

Comment: Ok thats a atart, but what is the correct format for its arguments? I am getting an error 400 Required' if I just change setMetadata to setCacheControl. So using the affected line as example, can you rewrite it with the correct arguments so the code works? Can see any example of this function's usage format on the internet.

Comment: I have tried "no-store", "private, max-age=0, no-transform","public, max-age=0, no-transform", "max-age=0"  all to no avail, same error 400 Required' response

Comment: Does `$obj->setCacheControl('Cache-Control: public, max-age=6000')` work?

Comment: Still getting  the same error  400 Required' .I think I had tried that before unsuccessfully.. still stuck with a one hour cache. But i thought a setMetadata would do it..anyway I just need something that would work, however it works. Thanks

Comment: Can you try setting it in the body, like this? `['name' => $file, 'mimeType' => 'text/html', 'data' =>   $infotowrite, 'uploadType' => 'media', 'cacheControl' => 'Cache-Control: public, max-age=6000']`

Comment: Another error this time : 'Google_Exception' with message '(insert) unknown parameter: 'cacheControl'' in /home/xxxxxx/google-api-php-client/bla-bla-bla....

Comment: I would have loved to offer a bounty on this question if I had enough reputation..if I could attract the google devs

Comment: @Rehoboth5467 - You are talking to a google dev :) Can you try this: `$obj->setCacheControl('public, max-age=6000')` ?

Comment: Well well I got lucky eh? Ok tried it but error 400. Message below:

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucketyyyy/o?uploadType=media: (400) Uploads must be sent to the upload URL. Re-send this request to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucketyyy/o?uploadType=media' .....bla bla

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31339117/624900) solve your problem?

Comment: No it does not. I made the suggested correction as in the link you supplied, while leaving `$obj->setCacheControl('public, max-age=6000')` unchanged and it still gives precisely the same PHP Fatal error

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucketyyy/o?uploadType=media: (400) Uploads must be sent to the upload URL. Re-send this request to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucketyyy/o?uploadType=media' in

Comment: /home/myaccount/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php:110\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/myaccount/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php(62): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request), Object(Google_Client))\n#1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))\n#2 /home/myaccount/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(174): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#3 /home/myaccount/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php(46): Google_Task_Runner->run()\n#4

Comment: /home/myaccount/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php(593): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))\n#5 /home/myaccount in /home/myaccount/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 110

Comment: @Rehoboth5467 Sorry for the delay. I tried it out and got it to work. Updated answer with working code.

Comment: setCacheControl is outdated, now it doesn't exist. you should use metadata.