# Google Cloud Storage PHP Api Disable cache while downloading

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have uploaded file to google cloud storage via their php API

I am trying to use following code now to access it back.

```
$bucket = $storage->bucket('my-bucket');
$object = $bucket->object('filename.json');
$string = $object->downloadAsString();
echo $string;
```

I am just trying to retrieve a json , But problem is its getting cached and keep giving me old file which I modified 30 mins back.

How to disable Cache ? While using downloadAsString ?something like

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/filename.json?id=randomtimestamp
```

P.s: I know Disabling cache while uploading json will work, but I just want to disable cache in few of my php scripts.

Comment: if you have Google storage utility (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) installed then you can use the following command to set cache control headers for selected file using this command `gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control:private, max-age=0, no-transform" gs://<bucket>/<path>/<filename>` eg. `gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control:private, max-age=0, no-transform" gs://bucket134/javascripts/load.js`

Comment: Please read my P.s

Comment: Above mentioned command is not needed to run at the time of upload. You can do it anytime. Second, check if you have versioning enabled on your bucket. If yes then try to switch it off if possible.

Comment: You can set this URL query parameter, like `?ignoreCache=1` with reference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37124554/1578466 answer.

Comment: how to use ignoreCache parameter inside downloadasstring funciton ? in php api ?

Comment: I am not much familiar with PHP but check if this answer helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/32233553/1578466

Comment: To get a broader context for the ?ignoreCache=1 URL query parameter, one may refer to the the [Cloud Storage XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/overview) : a RESTful interface that lets you manage Cloud Storage data in a programmatic way.