# Flysystem: Google Cloud Storage Adapter - cache-control

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, flysystem

Is there a way to set the cache-control metadata while putting a file to the Google Cloud Storage using  Google Cloud Storage Adapter for Flysystem?

I have all my files in the bucket public, but sometimes I need to update some file, and after that I still see the old file. I see it's possible in general, but I don't see a way to do this by Flysystem, and we use it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Flysystem has ability to set adapter config. To set cache control header for GCP buckets, you can use next:

```
/** @var FilesystemInterface $storage */
$storage->put($path, $contents, [
    'metadata' => [
        'cacheControl' => 'no-cache,max-age=0'
     ]
]);
```

Also, you can setup Cloud Function in the GCP console to set headers when objects saved to the bucket

Answer (score 0):

You may find a PHP example of setting cache control in the reply to the [Set Cache-Control php client on Google Cloud Storage Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228147/set-cache-control-php-client-on-google-cloud-storage-object).

Answer (score 0):

there are few ways to do this

1. manually on GSC sonsole ("Edit Metadata" in each file) - bad solution if you have tons of files
2. upload using gsutil

   ```
    gsutil -m -D -h Cache-Control:"Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000" cp -r <path to your folder> gs://yourbucketname/optionalfolder/
   ```
3. update meta [reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta)

   ```
    gsutil -m setmeta -h "Content-Type:text/html" \
     -h "Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600" \
     -h "Content-Disposition" gs://bucket/*.html
   ```

4. upload using API (PHP, Nodejs, Java, GO etc.) See SDK docs - there are alot of examples for each language.
5. create Google Load Balancer and set custom meta field "Cache-Control" : "public, max-age=3600"
   in this case you will have your own CDN's domain name and flexible settings
6. [best option] - create and deploy trigger script which will set meta (or anyting you want https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html) right after upload (google.storage.object.finalize event)

create new folder with two files **index.js** and **package.json**

**index.js**

```
enter const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();

exports.prepare = (file, context) => {
   console.log("prepare: set cache control:" + file.name);
   storage.bucket(file.bucket).file(file.name).setMetadata({cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000'}); 
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
   "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/storage": ">=5.8.0"
   }
}
```

and deploy this function in two steps

1. install and init cloud (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install)

   ```
    gcloud init
   ```
2. deploy (it will ask to enable api first - follow instructions)

   ```
    gcloud functions deploy prepare \
     --runtime nodejs12 \
     --trigger-resource gs://yourbacketname \
     --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
   ```